# NMEA sentences with unexpected characters

Tags: python, gps, hardware, nmea

I'm using python to read data from a u-blox NEO-M9N chip via i2c on my raspberry Pi.

For the moment, I haven't built the rest of the script but I'm a little confused by the output of the chip as it seems to include **characters that don't belong there, such as
°,¬, or Á**. Sometimes those seem to be replacements for characters that look alike: **021120 is correct for a few lines and then is replaced by 0²1±20**, which is not too far away.

The sentences might be correct for anything between 5 to 50 lines and then I'll get something like this (I've replaced part of the GPS coordinates with X but you get it):

```
$GNRMC,204107.00,A,XX.20¶46,N,XX.47371,E,0.844,,021±20,,,A,V*17
$GNRMC,204108.00¬A,XX.20603,N,XX.47454,E,0.921,,021120,,,A,V*1B
```

Any idea to what this could be due? I'm very sure this will mess up what I want to with the data afterwards...

---

Here the code I'm using to read the data:

```
import time
import json
import smbus
import logging 

BUS = None
address = 0x42
gpsReadInterval = 0.1
LOG = logging.getLogger()

# taken and (poorly) adapted from
# http://ava.upuaut.net/?p=768

def connectBus():
    global BUS
    BUS = smbus.SMBus(1)

def parseResponse(gpsLine):
    gpsChars = ''.join(chr(c) for c in gpsLine)
    if "GNRMC" not in gpsChars:
        return False
    
    print(gpsChars)

def readGPS():
    c = None
    response = []
    try:
        while True: # Newline, or bad char.
            c = BUS.read_byte(address)
            if c == 255:
                return False
            elif c == 10:
                break
            else:
                response.append(c)
        parseResponse(response)
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        connectBus()

connectBus()
while True:
    readGPS()
    time.sleep(gpsReadInterval)
```

Comment: looks to me like a problem with the bus; are you using the correct transmission rate? Or is something else not quite right with it? If you can't solve this, you can use the checksum to filter out lines with errors in to make sure they don't mess up what you want to do with it later.

Comment: @OliverMason that might be... I've left everything at default so maybe I need to tweak the baud rate. The only examples or tools I could find on SO/SparkFun are ones with Arduino or Python+Serial, nothing in Python using i2c... Will look into it more and see if that makes a change but probably will need to do it from my windows laptop, right?

Comment: The baud rate might be too high or too low, so that is a good place to start.

Comment: @OliverMason any insights on how I can find the perfect baud rate? When connecting the chip via USB to my windows laptop, it uses "COM4 9600" to talk to the u-blox software, so I'm assuming 9600 is the baud rate. When I try to use that setting on my RPi via i2c, I get even more garbage than before...

Comment: According to the integration manual (p.23), "The default baud rate is 38400 baud." (https://www.u-blox.com/en/docs/UBX-19014286) There's also a table of possible values, so if the default doesn't work, I'd suggest to simply try them all.

Comment: Why can't you just skip broken records? It's kinda a general rule when working with framed data incoming from an external source.

Comment: @I.G. I mean yeah, that's what I'm doing now. If the checksum is missing or doesn't match or lat/long are 0 I'll just skip it but I feel that there should be a better way... It ends up being quite a few records that go missing. I'm not buying a 10 updates a sec chip just to have to toss 70% of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, someone has solved it for me: [Fix special characters with closest equivalent without map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876545/fix-special-characters-with-closest-equivalent-without-map)

It is indeed a hardware issue but it can be fixed via software using this guy's answer