# Fix special characters with closest equivalent without map

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I'm getting output from a sensor (GPS) in Python and for some reason, the output is not entirely clean. I'm already using pynmea2 and its checksum to filter out the bad rows but I want to improve the acceptance rate.

If you look at some sample data from the sensor, you see that many characters are replaced with something that could be corrected by a human, such as ® = . or ³ = 3. Some on the other hand, are less clear, such as ¶ or ± or Ç = G and not C.

I've tried to research how I could fix this but short of creating a hardcoded map or search and replace, I can't come up with anything. Is there a library or a way to "clean up" my input to solve at least the obvious one and thus boost my acceptance rate?

```
nmea = [
    "$GNRMC,175230.00,A,5231.08575,N,01324.94302,E,0.099,,300321,,,A,V*17",
    "$GNRMC,175211.00,A,5231.08495,N,01324.94370,E,2.771,348.30,300321,,,A,V*0F",
    "$GNGGA,175140.00,5231.06514,N,01325.03302,E,1,11,1.22,33.9,M,42.1,Í,,*7F",
    "$GNRMC,175141.00,A,5231.06307,N,01³25.02563,E,16.734,234.24,300³21,,,A,V*3A",
    "$GNGÇA,175141.00,5231.06307,N,01325.02563,E,1,11,1®22,33.6,M,42.1,M,,*75",
    "$GNRMC,175142.00,A,5231.°6059,N,01325.01869,E,17.220,235.29,300321,,,A,V*38",
    "$GNGGA,175142.00,5231.06059,N,01325.01869,E,1,11,±.22,33.5,M,42.1,M,,*79",
    "$GNRMC,175143.00,A,5231.05861,N,01325.01218,E,16.¶45,238.31,300321,,,A,V*37",
    "$GNGGA,175143.00,5231.05861,N,013²5.01218,E,1,11,1.22,34.7,M,42.1,M,,*71",
    "$GNRMC,175144.00,A,5231.05689,N,01325.00574,E,16.090,241.36,300321,,,A,V*33",
    "$GNGGA,175144.00,5231.05689,N,01325.00574,E,1,11,1.28,36.0,M,42.1,M,,*7D",
    "$GNRMC,175145.00,A,5231.05478,N,01324.99957,E,16.045,240.96,300321,,,A,V*31",
    "$GNGGA,175145.00,5231.05478,N,01324.99957,E,1,11,1.22,36.8,M,42.1,M,,*7E",
    "$GNRMC,175146®00,A,5231.05277,N,01324.99327,E,15.832,241.30,300321,,,A,V*30",
    "$GNGGA,175146.00,5231.05277,N,01324.99327,E,1,11,1.22,37.3,M,42.1,M,,*73",
    "$GNGGA,175230.00,5231.08575,N,01324.94302,E,1,12,0.96,56.7,M,42.1,M,,*7D"]
```

Comment: What is the offending column supposed to contain?  It looks as if it may contain binary data that isn't being represented correctly?

Comment: @snakecharmerb what do you mean "offending column"? The faults are spread out at random in the data, there's no real pattern sadly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a one-bit error between `®/.`, `³/3`, `Í/M` (same bit):

```
>>> for c in s:
...     print(f'{c} {ord(c):08b}')
... 
® 10101110
. 00101110
³ 10110011
3 00110011
Í 11001101
M 01001101
```

You likely have a problem with your hardware.  Since the data is ASCII the high bit (bit 7) is supposed to always be a 0, so you could just filter the output if you can't fix the hardware issue:

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

nmea = [
    "$GNRMC,175230.00,A,5231.08575,N,01324.94302,E,0.099,,300321,,,A,V*17",
    "$GNRMC,175211.00,A,5231.08495,N,01324.94370,E,2.771,348.30,300321,,,A,V*0F",
    "$GNGGA,175140.00,5231.06514,N,01325.03302,E,1,11,1.22,33.9,M,42.1,Í,,*7F",
    "$GNRMC,175141.00,A,5231.06307,N,01³25.02563,E,16.734,234.24,300³21,,,A,V*3A",
    "$GNGÇA,175141.00,5231.06307,N,01325.02563,E,1,11,1®22,33.6,M,42.1,M,,*75",
    "$GNRMC,175142.00,A,5231.°6059,N,01325.01869,E,17.220,235.29,300321,,,A,V*38",
    "$GNGGA,175142.00,5231.06059,N,01325.01869,E,1,11,±.22,33.5,M,42.1,M,,*79",
    "$GNRMC,175143.00,A,5231.05861,N,01325.01218,E,16.¶45,238.31,300321,,,A,V*37",
    "$GNGGA,175143.00,5231.05861,N,013²5.01218,E,1,11,1.22,34.7,M,42.1,M,,*71",
    "$GNRMC,175144.00,A,5231.05689,N,01325.00574,E,16.090,241.36,300321,,,A,V*33",
    "$GNGGA,175144.00,5231.05689,N,01325.00574,E,1,11,1.28,36.0,M,42.1,M,,*7D",
    "$GNRMC,175145.00,A,5231.05478,N,01324.99957,E,16.045,240.96,300321,,,A,V*31",
    "$GNGGA,175145.00,5231.05478,N,01324.99957,E,1,11,1.22,36.8,M,42.1,M,,*7E",
    "$GNRMC,175146®00,A,5231.05277,N,01324.99327,E,15.832,241.30,300321,,,A,V*30",
    "$GNGGA,175146.00,5231.05277,N,01324.99327,E,1,11,1.22,37.3,M,42.1,M,,*73",
    "$GNGGA,175230.00,5231.08575,N,01324.94302,E,1,12,0.96,56.7,M,42.1,M,,*7D"]

def fix(m):
    a = m.group(0)
    b = chr(ord(m.group(0)) & 0x7F) # clear bit 7.
    print(f'Replaced {a} with {b}')
    return b

for i,v in enumerate(nmea):
    nmea[i] = re.sub(r'[\x80-\xff]',fix,v)

pprint(nmea)
```

Output:

```
Replaced Í with M
Replaced ³ with 3
Replaced ³ with 3
Replaced Ç with G
Replaced ® with .
Replaced ° with 0
Replaced ± with 1
Replaced ¶ with 6
Replaced ² with 2
Replaced ® with .
['$GNRMC,175230.00,A,5231.08575,N,01324.94302,E,0.099,,300321,,,A,V*17',
 '$GNRMC,175211.00,A,5231.08495,N,01324.94370,E,2.771,348.30,300321,,,A,V*0F',
 '$GNGGA,175140.00,5231.06514,N,01325.03302,E,1,11,1.22,33.9,M,42.1,M,,*7F',
 '$GNRMC,175141.00,A,5231.06307,N,01325.02563,E,16.734,234.24,300321,,,A,V*3A',
 '$GNGGA,175141.00,5231.06307,N,01325.02563,E,1,11,1.22,33.6,M,42.1,M,,*75',
 '$GNRMC,175142.00,A,5231.06059,N,01325.01869,E,17.220,235.29,300321,,,A,V*38',
 '$GNGGA,175142.00,5231.06059,N,01325.01869,E,1,11,1.22,33.5,M,42.1,M,,*79',
 '$GNRMC,175143.00,A,5231.05861,N,01325.01218,E,16.645,238.31,300321,,,A,V*37',
 '$GNGGA,175143.00,5231.05861,N,01325.01218,E,1,11,1.22,34.7,M,42.1,M,,*71',
 '$GNRMC,175144.00,A,5231.05689,N,01325.00574,E,16.090,241.36,300321,,,A,V*33',
 '$GNGGA,175144.00,5231.05689,N,01325.00574,E,1,11,1.28,36.0,M,42.1,M,,*7D',
 '$GNRMC,175145.00,A,5231.05478,N,01324.99957,E,16.045,240.96,300321,,,A,V*31',
 '$GNGGA,175145.00,5231.05478,N,01324.99957,E,1,11,1.22,36.8,M,42.1,M,,*7E',
 '$GNRMC,175146.00,A,5231.05277,N,01324.99327,E,15.832,241.30,300321,,,A,V*30',
 '$GNGGA,175146.00,5231.05277,N,01324.99327,E,1,11,1.22,37.3,M,42.1,M,,*73',
 '$GNGGA,175230.00,5231.08575,N,01324.94302,E,1,12,0.96,56.7,M,42.1,M,,*7D']
```

Comment: this is exactly it and has literally saved me from losing my mind! Thanks a million, also for the edits and the function! How did you conclude that it was this problem? Experience only or is there a "standard debugging route" that I could have followed in that case?

Comment: @DamienBourdonneau Experience. Random corruption is generally a signal quality issue, so I looked at the raw data bits to see if there was a pattern. I work in hardware test and debug issues like this all the time Might be an issue with clocking the data over a serial connection since it is always the same bit being metastable.

Comment: it most likely is - I'm accessing the sensor (u-blox neo-m9n) via i2c on a raspberry pi and get that "noise" but I don't when I plug it in via USB C on my laptop so I figured it might be something like that. I had played with changing the baud rates of the i2c interface according to the manual but it only led to more misses, not fewer. Your solution solves it though!

Comment: Since the replacements are 1-on-1 you could speed this up by using `str.translate()`; here `[*range(128), *range(128)]` would suffice as the translation table, but perhaps compare timings with `dict(zip(range(128, 256), range(128)))` as the map as well.